# User groups without Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003

Is it possible for Windows Server 2003 R2 to configure several user groups with different setups *without using Active Directory*?  The admin has turned it off for 'security reasons'.

Which *setups* I need:

I connect to a Windows Server remotely using RDP. And the server abrupts after 5 min of inactivity. The admin of the server doesn't want to increase the amount of time of inactivity for all users. I need more than 5 hours of inactivity because of a long running database task on the server.

Comment: There are some key details missing in this question. What "different permissions" and which "setups"? It's not clear what you're asking. Also _what_ has the admin turned off exactly?

Comment: @jscott, I've improved the question, hope it's more clear now. I don't know what exactly is turned off, but I was told that AD is turned off completely. Is it possible? I do not know. I came from Linux and Windows is a new context for me which I'm discovering now.

Comment: I literally snorted my tea and burst into laughter at reading about Active Directory being "turned off" for "security reasons". Your admin sounds terrible. Not relevant to your question but maybe start looking around for other opportunities where an "admin" who has such a poor grasp of technology and provides such poor customer service would not remain long, or even get hired in the first place.

Comment: "The admin has turned [Active Directory] off for 'security reasons'."  ...I can't even.  I no longer have a 2003 box available to test things for you, sorry.  I mainly wanted to point out the irony that your admin won't use AD for "security reasons" but is running post-end-of-life software that no longer receives security updates.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, I appreciate your comment, it's helpful for understanding of the whole situation I have to deal with. For me there is something fundamentally wrong with inability to increase time-out. And I'm completely new to Windows stack to deal with it confidently. But thank you.

Comment: @KatherineVillyard, thank you for your attitude to the question, it upgrades my vision of the whole.